# LaunchMap can not be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I'm  trying to launch the google maps application on my android project. When I'm writing: `if(view.getId()= =R.id.LaunchMap);`, 
it produces an error:

> LaunchMap can not be resolved or is not a field

To solve it, it shows suggestions:

1. create constant 'LaunchMap' in type 'id'.
2. create field 'LaunchMap' in type 'id'.
3. rename in file.

When I try the first 2 suggestions in R.java, the console produces an error:

> R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

What is the solution??

Answer (score 2):

First the `R` file is generated when you build your project you should not manually edit that file.

Second you have to define LunchMap id in your xml file to use it in your code.for example

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/LaunchMap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```